# How to display html as a tree in Swing?

Tags: java, html, swing

I would like to display html as treeview similar to firebug in my swing. Looking for community help to achieve this. Found similar stuff(Not Exactly) [here](http://www.wsoftware.de/SpeedJG/XMLTreeView.html). But i could not move further with the information in the link.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want, but I suppose this article will be useful for you: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19666.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need a HTML DOM parser (like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)) to create a DOM tree from the HTML code you have. Then you should probably build your own [`TreeModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) to respresent the DOM tree in a swing `JTree`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html to see how it could be implemented.

After reading HTML with `HTMLEditorKit` use the HTMLDocument's tree.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://www.ananta.com/docs/j2eetutorial14/doc/JAXPDOM4.html) will tell you exactly how to create a JTree that shows the DOM structure of an HTML document.